# Codenvy Bitbucket Integration

Tags: bitbucket, codenvy

I tried going to CodeEnvy to make a new Android Workspace for my project hosted on Bitbucket

[image]

I got the following error

> Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered

I checked the [Codenvy Documentation](http://codenvy.readme.io/docs/authentication), but it said:

> ou need to register your Codenvy installation at different oAuth providers.

[image]

I don't know what they mean. I am trying to use the online version not install anything. What callback URL should I add to Bitbucket OAuth?

Answer (score 1):

I'm no Codeenvy user, but I did have a look and it seems like Codeenvy doesn't really have Bitbucket integration. Instead, they allow you to import from any URL.

What you seem to be running into is that your repo is private, while Codeenvy does not support you to pass in credentials and so it can't clone the repo.

It seems like the only solution to that is to tell it to clone over SSH (your screenshot has an https://bitbucket.org/.. URL). Now before you do that, you will have to manually create an SSH key pair in Codeenvy and then upload to your Bitbucket account settings (Bitbucket Settings -> SSH Keys).

It's all a bit clumsy, but this might provide some context: https://groups.google.com/a/codenvy.com/forum/#!topic/codenvy/v6Vyc797UDk

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new empty workspace in Codenvy. Then, after launch, open the termina and run the git clone command like:
git clone https://@bitbucket.org/project-name/repository-name.git

After a while, Codenvy will recognize git VCS and will give you commands in the VCS-GIT menu